Proving that user has always less money than bank
I would like to create simple bank application in idris.
I have prepared Bank type:
data Bank : Type where
  Init : Bank
  Deposit : Bank -> Address -> Nat -> Bank
  Withdraw : (s : Bank) -> (a : Address) -> (x : Nat) -> (p : LTE x (userDeposit s a)) -> Bank

It is possible to init such Bank, deposit or withdraw some Nats to/from specific Address.
Withdraw is only possible if amount to withdraw is less than user deposit for previous state.
Function userDeposit is self describing:
total userDeposit : (s : Bank) -> (a : Address) -> Nat
userDeposit Init a = 0
userDeposit (Deposit s a x) b = case addrEq a b of
    Yes Refl => add x (userDeposit s a)
    No _ => userDeposit s b
userDeposit (Withdraw s a x p) b = case addrEq a b of
    Yes Refl => sub (userDeposit s a) x p
    No _ => userDeposit s b

It is using two arithmetic functions add and sub:
total sub : (x, y : Nat) -> LTE y x -> Nat
sub x 0 p = x
sub (S x) (S y) (LTESucc p) = sub x y p

total add : (x, y : Nat) -> Nat
add x 0 = x
add x (S y) = S (add x y)

I also wanted to have totalDeposit function, but it is a bit problematic:
total totalDeposit : (s : Bank) -> Nat
totalDeposit Init = 0
totalDeposit (Deposit s a x) = add x (totalDeposit s)
totalDeposit (Withdraw s a x p) = sub (totalDeposit s) x (transitive p (lteUserTotal s a))

I can't just subtract x from previous totalDeposit, because I don't have required proof. I could store such redundant proof, but I don't want to do it, because LTE x (userDeposit s a)) should be enough if I prove LTE (userDeposit s a) (totalDeposit s).
I thought it is easy, but I can't prove one case:
total lteUserTotal : (s : Bank) -> (a : Address) -> LTE (userDeposit s a) (totalDeposit s)
lteUserTotal Init a = LTEZero
lteUserTotal (Deposit s b x) a with (addrEq b a)
  lteUserTotal (Deposit s a x) a | Yes Refl = ?op_rhs_0 (lteUserTotal s a) --easy
  lteUserTotal (Deposit s b x) a | No _ = ?op_rhs_1 (lteUserTotal s a) --easy
lteUserTotal (Withdraw s b x p) a with (addrEq b a)
  lteUserTotal (Withdraw s a x p) a | Yes Refl = ?op_rhs_2 (lteUserTotal s a) --easy
  lteUserTotal (Withdraw s b x p) a | No _ = ?op_rhs_3 (lteUserTotal s a) --IMPOSSIBLE for me

This is the case, when b withdraws, so a deposit remains the same.
I have no idea how to solve it:
op_rhs_3 : LTE (userDeposit s a) (totalDeposit s) -> 
           LTE (userDeposit s a) (sub (totalDeposit s) x (transitive p (lteUserTotal s b)))

Anyone knows how to solve my problem without storing proof, that withdraw amount is less than total deposit?
Full code here: https://gist.github.com/SecuFather/6c54f8f757ec0b64070e351906eb6b31

You may have to prove something stronger, like "the sum of deposits of any set of addresses is less than the total deposit", for the induction to work.

It might be easier to replace userDeposit with userDeposits: a map from addresses to balances. Then you can trivially get userDeposit and totalDeposit from that.

After many attempts I have finally proved, that total balance is at least as big as user balance.
Firstly, I have modified Bank data structure. I have added new constructor Open and address is now Fin. Bank also stores number of accounts in its type.
data Bank : (n : Nat) -> Type where
    Init : Bank 0
    Open : Bank n -> Bank (S n)
    Deposit : Bank n -> (addr : Fin n) -> (amount : Nat) -> Bank n
    Withdraw : (b : Bank n) -> (addr : Fin n) -> (amount : Nat) -> (p : LTE amount (userBalance b addr)) -> Bank n

userBalance function now returns 0 on the last possible Open constructor. The rest remains similar:
total userBalance : Bank n -> (addr : Fin n) -> Nat
userBalance (Open b) FZ = 0
userBalance (Open b) (FS addr) = userBalance b addr
userBalance (Deposit b a amount) addr = case decEq addr a of
    Yes Refl => add (userBalance b addr) amount
    No _ => userBalance b addr
userBalance (Withdraw b a amount p) addr = case decEq addr a of
    Yes Refl => sub (userBalance b addr) amount p
    No _ => userBalance b addr

Now, the most important part, totalBalance function. I don't make pattern matching on Bank anymore. Instead I'm adding last userBalance to recursive totalBalance. At the end of recursion - for Bank having no accounts I return 0. I had to find the way, how to make Bank structurally smaller without looking at the Bank content. I just needed pop function, which would remove all the actions on last account. It is not so trivial, because I had to preserve actions for all but last addresses.
total totalBalance : {n : Nat} -> Bank n -> Nat
totalBalance b {n = 0} = 0
totalBalance b {n = (S n)} = add (totalBalance (pop b)) (userBalance b FZ)

While implementing pop function, I have noticed that I need to prove, that userBalance remains the same after pop to construct Withdraw for all but last addresses:
total pop : Bank (S n) -> Bank n
pop (Open b) = b
pop (Deposit b FZ amount) = pop b
pop (Deposit b (FS addr) amount) = Deposit (pop b) addr amount
pop (Withdraw b FZ amount p) = pop b
pop (Withdraw b (FS addr) amount p) = Withdraw (pop b) addr amount $ rewrite sym $ userBalanceSameAfterPop b addr in p

userBalanceSameAfterPop turned out to be the longest function, but only withdraw case requires more work, than simple recursion.
total userBalanceSameAfterPop : (b : Bank (S n)) -> (addr : Fin n) -> userBalance b (FS addr) = userBalance (pop b) addr
userBalanceSameAfterPop (Open b) addr = Refl
userBalanceSameAfterPop (Deposit b FZ amount) addr = userBalanceSameAfterPop b addr
userBalanceSameAfterPop (Deposit b (FS a) amount) addr with (decEq addr a)
    userBalanceSameAfterPop (Deposit b (FS addr) amount) addr | Yes Refl = rewrite userBalanceSameAfterPop b addr in Refl
    userBalanceSameAfterPop (Deposit b (FS a) amount) addr | No c = userBalanceSameAfterPop b addr
userBalanceSameAfterPop (Withdraw b FZ amount p) addr = userBalanceSameAfterPop b addr
userBalanceSameAfterPop (Withdraw b (FS a) amount p) addr with (decEq addr a)
    userBalanceSameAfterPop (Withdraw b (FS addr) amount p) addr | Yes Refl = rewrite userBalanceSameAfterPop b addr in
        prf where
            total prf : {x, y : Nat} -> {p1, p2 : LTE y x} -> sub x y p1 = sub x y p2
            prf {y = 0} = Refl
            prf {p1 = (LTESucc p1)} {p2 = (LTESucc p2)} = prf
    userBalanceSameAfterPop (Withdraw b (FS a) amount p) addr | No c = userBalanceSameAfterPop b addr

After this, I was ready for final proof. Having pop and userBalanceSameAfterPop makes it piece of cake:
total lteUserTotal : {n : Nat} -> (b : Bank n) -> (addr : Fin n) -> LTE (userBalance b addr) (totalBalance b)
lteUserTotal b FZ {n = (S n)} = lteAddLeft
lteUserTotal b (FS addr) {n = (S n)} = rewrite userBalanceSameAfterPop b addr in 
    transitive (lteUserTotal (pop b) addr) lteAddRight

Full code here: https://gist.github.com/SecuFather/6c54f8f757ec0b64070e351906eb6b31
Maybe someone will find it useful.
Thank you @NaïmFavier for showing me a good direction.
